# iPhone xs Max background after 3 minute Operation not permitted

Tags: ios, iphone, background, operation

### Build Information

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true).first!
do{
    self.db = try Connection("(path)/test.sqlite3")
    createGeoLocationTableIfNotExists()
}catch let err{
    print("sqlite db conntect failed: (err)")
}
```

- pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11.4'   issue.
- xcode 10.1 (10B61),  iphone xs Max 12  and  iphone 6 11

### log 2019-02-26 16:01:21.772554+0800 test[3572:1023842] [logging] os_unix.c:37220: (1) seekAndRead(/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7B491B30-5794-4224-A648-1A589BE6734F/Documents/test.sqlite3) - Operation not permitted

in foreahead, it works ok, but in background after 3 minute not working. I use in location update .
but same code run ok in iphone 6 plus.
in simulator both run ok.

Someone have a clue to solve it?

thanks

Comment: Any chance you activated Data Protection Capabilitiy and set it to CompleteProtection?

Comment: Data Protection status is off

Comment: May I see the code where you create the test.sqlite3 database?

Comment: it'a a Singleton class. when app is open, then create the test.sqlite3 database

Comment: it happen when the test.sqlite3 database file is big